# AWS EC2 instances using VPN connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpn

I would setup an VM on EC2 which connect to a VPN. As a result, all traffic to the Internet from this EC2 go through the VPN.

[image]

1. I setup an EC2 `A` with a eth0, 1 EIP, 1 private IP from one of the predefined subnet in default VPC
2. Setup another EC2 `B` with a eth0, 1 EIP, 1 private IP from the same subnet of `A`
3. Install the VPN client in `A`
4. Establish the connection to the VPN in `A`, ssh to `A` from EIP is loss as expected
5. Checked that `A` could reach the internet via VPN
6. I can admin `A` by ssh to `B` EIP then ssh to `A` private IP

Now I would create more worker VMs `C`, `D`, `E`. The workers would go to the internet via the VPN, but the VPN has connection limit. Therefore, I would share the connection in `A` to `C`, `D`, `E`. and I also would admin `C`, `D`, `E` through `B`.

- `C`, `D`, `E` are created in a new subnet, which has the Route table configure `0.0.0.0/0` to the instance `A`'s `eth0`
- `B` could ssh into `C`, `D`, `E` by their private IP
- `A` is an ubuntu, `/etc/sysctl.conf` added `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- `Subnet 1` is predefined subnet in default VPC, using predefined route table, i.e. `0.0.0.0/0` via pre-created `igw`
- `Subnet 4` is a subnet I created, e.g. `172.31.128.0/20`, using another route table, which `0.0.0.0/0` via `A`'s `eth0`

**But `C`, `D`, `E` still cannot reach the internet.**

**Did I miss config something in EC2 / VPC / Route Table ????**

Comment: Did I miss some config in C, D, E? or my VPC / Route Table / EC2 configuration problem?

Comment: Does it work for you? Are you experiencing a problem (eg Why C, D, E doesn't work)? Or are you just asking for feedback on the general concept?

Comment: Not working. In my case, `A` is connect to Internet via VPN, but I cannot get `C,D,E` to connect to the Internet via VPN.

Comment: @kkpoon did you configure instance A with an `iptables -t nat ... -j MASQUERADE` entry?  If not, the traffic is being sent out the VPN with the original instance's address as the source address, which the VPN would be unlikely to understand or expect.